# Using two versions of jQuery and the simplest, most code-efficient method of noConflict

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a widget which runs within a framework that I have no control over. My widget uses an up-to-date version of jQuery where the framework uses some fairly horrendous old version.

Recently I've been having some problems with my code and I (eventually) worked out that it was a jQuery conflict issue.

The widget format is a bit bizarre, and is run as an iframe within this framework/template.

It uses the `widget.onload` function instead of any jQuery doc ready function. I tend to run one or two functions in there to initialise a separate class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    MyClass = {
        init : function() {
            // Where I build my "pseudo-class"
        }
    }

    widget.onLoad = function(){
        /* My code goes here */

        MyClass.init();
    };

//]]>
</script>
```

This isn't a problem - it's just context - and usually I can run jQuery as normal as follows:

```
widget.onLoad = function(){
    /* My code goes here */

    var id = $('a.student_iframe_popup').attr("id");
    MyClass.init(id);
};
```

I also reference other scripts within my widget as normal in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/user/74/187887.js"></script> <!-- jQuery 1.10.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/user/74/188165.js"></script> <!-- jQuery bPopup -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/user/74/188166.html"></script> <!-- Student Flags Iframe Popup -->
```

The last script I've linked there is just a simple function that I intend to use in a number of my widget scripts:

```
  $('body').on("click", ".student_iframe_popup", function() {
        $('body').append('<iframe></iframe>');

    var student_id = 'student_' + $(this).attr("id");

    $('iframe').attr("width", 800);
    $('iframe').attr("height", 600);
    $('iframe').attr("id", student_id);
    $('iframe').attr("src", '/index.phtml?d=825090');

    $('iframe').bPopup({
        modalClose: true,
        escClose: true,
              opacity: 0,
        position: ['auto', 10]
    });
  });
```

This all works fine - except that in IE, with some of my widgets, I get random bugs. If I change my code to utilise the following...

```
widget.onLoad = function(){
    /* My code goes here */
    jQuery.noConflinct();

    var id = jQuery('a.student_iframe_popup').attr("id");
    MyClass.init(id);
};
```

And change my referenced script from `$` to `jQuery` everything works fine - the "bugs" magically disappear.

However, I use a *lot* of dollar signs in my scripts and now that I've `CTRL+H` replaced `$` with `jQuery` everything has become vastly more difficult to read and it will naturally take me longer to type new code.

If I was writing a normal HTML/JS document I know I could use the following code to continue using `$(blah)` instead of `jQuery(blah)`:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
    $( "div" ).hide();
});
```

But as I'm not using the document ready functionality I have no idea how to implement that variant of noConflict.

Can anyone provide a better alternative that will work within my widget framework?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `ready()`, you can just create a closure and pass jQuery as an argument:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

An additional note: load order is important here, if `jQuery.bPopup` is loading an additional version of jQuery (which, from your explanation, it sounds like it is), it will overwrite jQuery (unless it is loading jQuery in noconflict mode itself). You may need to do something like after you load jQuery 1.10, but *before* the `<script>` tag that loads the plugin:

```
// --- before jquery.bPopup is loaded
var jQ-1.10.2 = jQuery.noConflict(true); // alias jQuery-1.10.2

(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery-1.10.2
  });
})(jQ-1.10.2);

// --- after jQuery.bPopup is loaded
// outside of closure $ refers to jQuery.bPopup version of jQuery
```

Comment: Hi Nick, that's a great answer, thank you. bPopup isn't the problem here - my widget page runs as an iframe within another page and THAT page runs a different version of jQuery. Therefore I don't think the loading should be a massive problem. Will your example work if I then use `$` in the `MyClass` class if I run `MyClass.init` from within the closure you've suggested?

Comment: @dunc I may not completely understand your implementation, but yes, ``$`` should work with your ``MyClass`` within the closure. Hope that helps!